# How can I dynamically resize Word margins based on a combobox selection in VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word, combobox, margins

I'm using Word365 to create a Binder template so users can dynamically create binder cover sheets and spine labels. I have already set up the template as follows:

Page 1: user inputs binder information
Page 2: binder cover page (output from page 1) - new section
Page 3: spine label page (output from page 1) - new section

Page 1 has
legacy combobox "BinderSize" - lists binder spine size choices for user to pick for creation
legacy textboxes "BinderNum" and "BinderTotal" - binder numbering (Binder X of Y)
legacy textbox "Title"
legacy textbox "RefDocs" - for listing any reference or attached documentation included in the binder

Each of the legacy textboxes is tied to a property field so the information input by the user is duplicated in the appropriate section.

Basically, all I need is know how to call the "BinderSize"value on update to dynamically resize the margins for the spine label page. I've never used VBA in Word and have no idea where to start. I've got a little bit of background/foundation in VBA from using it in Access to do simple things. So any help/guidance would is immensely appreciated as I know you are all busy with your own projects and lives.

I've already set up the document to duplicate the information where it needs to be and populated the combobox with the binder spine sizes we use.

Comment: A starting point would be to record the task as a macro.  Don't use the macro code as is, but it will provide useful pointers for generating your own code.

Answer (score 0):

At the top left of the `ThisDocument` module you'll see a drop-down list of objects which will include your combo-box. Selecting the name of the combo-box will create a `Change` event handler where you can put your code.

Page setup is per section in a Word document so you'll need to [change the margins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.pagesetup) for the relevant section

Answer (score 0):

Binders are only manufactured in 6 sizes, so a macro may not be necessary. You can create 2 pages with all the sizes on them. Use a Word table to format with rows or columns set to the spine widths and put the text in bookmarks so your macro can update them.

Or create a single table cell with a variable width and set that width with VBA. Then set up text to float in the middle of the cell, so changing the dimensions with VBA automatically keeps the text centered. This is a bit simpler than changing page margins. This macro assumes you're changing the width to 3" on a 12" tall table on a legal-size page:

```
Sub SetTableWidth()
    With ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Columns(1)
        .PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPoints
        .PreferredWidth = InchesToPoints(3)
    End With
End Sub
```